# Ester reacts with acyl chloride

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have worked with a somewhat long reaction sequence and got stuck on this last step. Im not sure if the entire sequence is even correct but this is what i came up with. Is this a possible reaction, if so, what is the product?
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Read about the formation of amides. You should use an equivalent of triethylamine as a "scavenger" base. Do you know why?  By the way, we are here to help, not do your homework. Let's see some effort.

Comment: The ester group is not involved in the reaction. Examine the role of the -NH2 group

Comment: Nucleophile  attacks electrophile, what can donate electrons in this scenario and what compound is electron deficient in this scenario..

Comment: Thank you for the answers.I will look into more about amides.